# What is $E(u_i| X_i)$ if $Y=\beta_0 + \beta_1X_i + u_i$ when $X$ is a dummy variable?

Tags: categorical-data, econometrics, expected-value, residuals

Here is the progress I made, I am just unsure. (This is not a question from a homework assignment or a text book. Thank you for your time.)

\begin{align*}
E(u_i| X_i) & =E(Y-\beta_0 - \beta_1X_i  | X_i) \\
&= E(Y| X_i)-E(\beta_0| X_i) - \beta_1E(X_i| X_i)\\
&=\beta_0 + \beta_1X_i-\beta_0 - \beta_1X_i \\
&= 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: How did you get $E[Y|X_i] = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_i$? Typically in a regression problem we are given an assumption such as $E[u_i] = 0$ to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is circular, and so it's incorrect. Flowsnake is right. You need to have this by assumption. You cannot prove the error has mean zero from other parts.

Your mistake is in the third line where you say
$$
E[Y|X_i] = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_i.
$$
This is not true unless you are assuming that which is to be shown.

Edit: responding to your question, if you assume the unconditional mean is zero, then usually you also assume that the errors are uncorrelated with the $X$s. In this case the two types of expectations will be equal. So there is no deduction required here, either.

Comment: $E(u_i)$ was assumed to be 0. You are right, I should have stated that. Can we say what I came up with is correct given that the error has mean zero?

Comment: @melihartar see my edit. If $E(u_i) = 0$ and $X_i$ and $u_i$ are independent, then $f(u|x) = f(u)$ and so $E[u_i|x_i] = E[u_i] = 0$.